# Concatenate values in columns/rows and getting the value of the result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel worksheet with something like below. The desired output are as shown in column G and the last row, which concatenates all the values in columns/rows and gives the value of the resultant expression.

It's actually some kind of a puzzle where the aim is to replace some numbers with operators such that the values in G matches with a specified value. I am replicating the same in excel from a paper version.

```
A     B     C    D    E    F    G

            3    3              33       
      4     1    +    2         43
4     0     +    5    6    4    604
7     3     2    /    1    2    61
      3     7    2    7         3727
            3    0              30
47  4033   304  0.4 2617   42
```

I have tried the following formula:

```
="="&A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2
```

However it gives the result in text format instead of 43, which I expected:

```
=41+2
```

Is there any way to give the final output as 43.

I developed (recorded and modified) a macro which simply copies the above result, paste it as values in Column H and then run 'text to columns' on the column H which gives me the desired output exactly as expected. However, I still can't figure out how to do the same with the row.

Is there any way to achieve the above with a formula only?

I want to avoid using macros as the undo functionality is lost but suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It can be done using forumlas in several cells.  Firstly I would do a formula that looks to see if the cells contain an operator. (+ - */) - If there is no operator then the cell concatenates the values.  If the cells do contain an operator, I would have a cell that gets the values to the left of the operator, and a cell that gets the values to the right of the operator.  Then in the final column, I would use an IF statement to either add/subtract/multiply/divide depending on what operator is found.

Comment: Some of your expected answers don't match what you state : 3737 for example has 3727 in the cells, also, 604 when 4 is the first.

Comment: @Solar Mike 40+564 gives 604.  3737 is a typing error. Should be 3727.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a UDF that uses `Application.Evaluate` to evaluate the text string into a value. Then your formula would just need `=Eval(A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2)`

```
Function Eval(txt As String)
    Eval = Application.Evaluate(txt)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, works exactly the way I wanted and learnt something new as well!   Next topic to research: UDF's in excel. :)